# linux timeval gettimeofday printf error

Tags: c, linux, time, struct, system-calls

The function displayTimeDifference is not working properly; the issue is that the printf statement is failing. After Googling the format of the printf statement when using a timeval is correct. Not sure why I can't print out the value of the timeval. I'm not getting any system errors from gettimeofday().

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct timeval *timeBefore;
struct timeval *timeAfter;
char * Buffer;

double malloctest(const int, const int, const int);
double calloctest(const int, const int, const int);
double allocatest(const int, const int, const int);
void   displayTimeDifference();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    malloctest(3072, 10, 10);
    return 0;
}

double malloctest(const int objectsize, const int numobjects, const int numtests)
{
    int i;
    int retVal;
    for (i = 1; i < numtests; i++) {
        if ((retVal = gettimeofday(timeBefore, NULL)) != 0) {
            printf("ERROR: gettimeofday failed with code: %d\n", retVal);
        }

        Buffer = (char*)malloc(objectsize * sizeof(char));

        if ((retVal = gettimeofday(timeAfter, NULL)) != 0) {
            printf("ERROR: gettimeofday failed with code: %d\n", retVal);
        }

        displayTimeDifference();
    }

    return 0.0;
}



void displayTimeDifference()
{
    printf("Time in microseconds: %ld microseconds\n", (timeAfter->tv_sec - timeBefore->tv_sec));
}
```

Comment: where is it failing? did you debug it? what's with `Buffer`? What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: Note that although you claim to print microseconds, you attempt to calculate the difference between the two times in seconds.  You have to do quite a bit more work in case you get time before of 123.987654 and a time after of 125.012987.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`gettimeofday`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) needs a valid pointer to `struct timeval`, where it can save the informations, you call it with a `NULL` pointer.

you should change

```
struct timeval *timeBefore;
struct timeval *timeAfter;
```

to

```
struct timeval timeBefore;
struct timeval timeAfter;
```

and the calls to `gettimeofday(&timeBefore, NULL)` and `gettimeofday(&timeAfter, NULL)`. You check the return value of this function and print something, but your program continues as it was successfully.

Also
`printf("Time in microseconds: %ld microseconds\n", (timeAfter->tv_sec - timeBefore->tv_sec));`
to
`printf("Time in seconds: %ld microseconds\n", (timeAfter.tv_sec - timeBefore.tv_sec));`.
You are only calculating the seconds, not the microseconds.

Another possibility is to `malloc` the memory for the pointer, but that is not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in another answer you have wrongly declared the struct timeval as pointers. 
I share my timing macros:

```
#define START_TIMER(begin)  gettimeofday(&begin, NULL) // ;

#define END_TIMER(end)      gettimeofday(&end,   NULL) // ;

//get the total number of sec:
#define ELAPSED_TIME(elapsed, begin, end) \
    elapsed = (end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) \
    + ((end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec)/1000000.0) // ;
```

Where you have to define the variables:

```
struct timeval begin, end;
double elapsed;
```

Comment: 'Tis curious that you force an assignment inside what could otherwise be a useful expression.  Because you use `double`, you avoid problems which you run into with the difference if you maintain the time in seconds separately from the time in microseconds (as in 125.012987 - 123.987345).  If you separate the seconds and microseconds, you have to deal with negative microseconds and compensating additions and subtractions.

Comment: Also, get rid of the semicolons after the `#define` lines.  They are wrong.  If a user wrote: `if (onevar == twovar) ELAPSED_TIME(t_delta, t1, t2); else ELAPSED_TIME(t_delta, t3, t4);`, the code won't compile.  Similarly with the start timer and end timer macros.

Comment: Amongst others, see [Strange errors using timeval struct and gettimeofday — because of semicolons in `#define`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177547).